# where to add null in file read

Tags: c, file

While reading a file into char *, where should the null be added and why? Option1 or option2, both seem to compile.

```
char* load_file(char const* path)
{
    char* buffer = 0;
    long length;
    FILE * f = fopen (path, "rb"); 

    if (f)
    {
        fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
        length = ftell (f);
        fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        buffer = (char*)malloc ((length+1)*sizeof(char));
        if (buffer)
        {
            fread (buffer, sizeof(char), length, f);
        }
        fclose (f);
    }
    buffer[length] = '\0'; //option1
    buffer[length+1] = '\0'; //Option2
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Option 1. BTW, sizeof(char) is always 1, so it's redundant to use such an expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your `malloc` call you allocate an "array" of `length + 1` characters, with indexes from `0` to `length` (inclusive). Therefore the correct option can only be "option1".

Comment: Can option 2 compile being out of range though? Is it because it's C?

Comment: @Shinratensei Yes option 2 is out of bounds. It will compile though since C have no bounds-checking.